# Is it possible to use onboard graphics for Ubuntu and dedicated card for Windows?

Tags: 12.04, graphics, windows, amd-graphics

I'm having lots of problems with my ATI Radeon HD5670 card on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I've tried all the possible drivers and they were all giving me frequent freezes and slowdowns which is not at all usable.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use my onboard video (GeForce 6 or 7 series) when on Ubuntu and use the ATI card on Windows? Is this possible without taking out my GPU physically? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it desktop or Portable system.

Comment: It's a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  You can use any graphics output you have modules for.  If you do not want to use the ATI Radeon HD5670 you can blacklist the module and it will not load and fall back to the GeForce if modules are available.